# Configure production environment for react-create-app at aws elasticbeanstalk

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, create-react-app

I have deployed react-create-app at aws elastic-beanstalk and it is running in development environment.

How to configure production environment?

Answer (score 2):

When building with `npm run build`, `NODE_ENV` is always set to `'production'`

> There is also a special built-in environment variable called NODE_ENV. You can read it from process.env.NODE_ENV. When you run npm start, it is always equal to 'development', when you run npm test it is always equal to 'test', and when you run npm run build to make a production bundle, it is always equal to 'production'. You cannot override NODE_ENV manually. This prevents developers from accidentally deploying a slow development build to production.

source : https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#adding-custom-environment-variables

Comment: Thanks for replying. So I have to mentions **npm run build** in Node Command box of aws elastic-beanstalk config file.

Comment: Yes, `npm run start` is only for development, when you deploy you should only send files from `build` directory. Then you can run it with `serve` or whatever you want. [ref](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#deployment)

Comment: After changing the same, I am getting **502 Bad Gateway

nginx/1.12.1** error.

Comment: Following are the my configuration - 

proxy server - **Nginx**,

Node command - **npm install -g serve && serve -s build**,

and I have uploaded the build folder zip while deployment.

Still I am getting **502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.12.1 error**

Comment: Sounds good, check the [logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html)

Comment: `serve` default port is 5000 make sure to adapt your config or choose an other one.

Comment: I have configured nginx proxy according to [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-proxy.html] by creating a **.ebextensions/proxy.config**

After this I am getting following error in my log file- 
**connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream,...upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000....**

Can you please help to find what is missing in configuration?